# django comments custom tag not working?

Tags: python, django, tags

I am  learning python and django, trying "learning-website-development-with-django", I have done creating projects successfully until comments application. But while adding django's comments application's custom tags i am getting this issue, though I am not getting any error ... following line is printed in html as it is.

```
{% get_comment_count for usernews.sharedbookmark shared_bookmark.id as comment_count %}
```

I have added `{% load comments %}` before.

I have set `TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True` ,  in the settings file. I couldn't understand why it is happening.

Comment: What issue are you getting? Have you included `django.contrib.comment` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: make sure that `usernews.sharedbookmark` and `shared_bookmark.id` are not `None`

Comment: @SkylarSaveland I have checked both :(, both are  ok

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony ys, I did not forget to do that